# C# Method("item one" | "item two") meaning/execution

Tags: c#, operators

I have seen the following type of code before:

```
Method("item one" | "item two")
```

What exactly does it do? In my code I have.

```
IsInRole(RoleEnum.Administrator | RoleEnum.Moderator)
```

How I would expect it to happen is that it checks is in role Administrator OR Moderator but it returns false, when the user is just in Administrator. I am not sure what it is called when you do that but I am interested in knowing what it exactly does and the reasoning/times you could use something like that.

Comment: The term "bitwise or" will help you fidn the answer. It won't work with strings though. If you have a question about why your code isn't working, show your code.

Comment: This [reference link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_bitwise_operators.htm) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`|` performs the bitwise OR of the inputs. Similarly `&` performs the bitwise AND. So if in a method, you pass:

1. ((1)<sub>10</sub> | (2)<sub>10</sub>): The call will be effectively passed ((00000001)<sub>2</sub> | (00000010)<sub>2</sub>) = (3)<sub>10</sub>
2. ((1)<sub>10</sub> & (2)<sub>10</sub>): The call will be effectively passed ((00000001)<sub>2</sub> & (00000010)<sub>2</sub>) = (0)<sub>10</sub>

---

One common instance where it is heavily used and which forms the most basic version of Computer Security is *file-permissions*. The [Numeric Notation in File System Permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Numeric_notation) is essentially a use of bitwise ANDing and ORing to decide what permission a user/group have over a particular file.

Comment: `|` could also mean the **logical** OR of the inputs though that is highly unlikely in this case.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I didn't come across such case yet... Which language does that?

Comment: The language in the question, `C#`. `|` can operate on both integers (bitwise OR) and booleans (logical OR). In the case of boolean operands, the difference between `|` and `||` is that `||` will short-circuit, meaning that if the evaluation of the first operand is `true` then there is no point in evaluating the second operand, whereas `|` will always evaluate both.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Really!? Please do point me to some example of such case. I would be happy to learn. :)

Comment: `a() || b()` will not even call `b()` if `a()`  returns `true` since the final outcome is  already known. If you use `| ` instead, then both `a()` and `b()` will be called, regardless of what `a()` returns.

Comment: Same difference with `&` vs. `&&`.

Comment: But again, all of this is highly unlikely with this question, more than likely that these are just enums being bitwise OR'ed together.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yes, it may not be related to the question, but it is definitely nice to learn more. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: What you have pointed to is called *Short-circuiting*. I found it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.140).aspx Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the answer is that, no you can't do it that way. `IPrincipal.IsInRole` takes a string, not an enumeration value.

To fix your problem, you need to use the logical or operator, and restructure the call like this:

```
IsInRole(RoleEnum.Administrator) || IsInRole(RoleEnum.Moderator)
```

(Assuming that the values in `RoleEnum` are strings. If not, see the end for more info.)

So what does the `|` operator do? It is the bitwise or operator. Lets say we have two binary numbers `0100` and `0010`.  The or operator combines them, by looking at each bit position, and if either (or both) is a 1 then the same position in the result is a 1.  For the two numbers above its

```
0100 |
0010 =
0110
```

Modern processors have a number of this kind of operator built in, and as such these operations are incredibly fast.

For enumerations, C# allows you to also specify the `Flags` attribute, which says that each member of the enumeration, by default, represents a single bit in the number representation of the value.  This allows for quick combinations and testing of flags, and allows the storage of 32 values in a single standard `int`. This works because the internal type of all enumerations is one of the core numeric types.

---

If the values in `RoleEnum` aren't strings, and it's an actual `enum` type, then some modifications need to be made. For the sake of argument, let's define `RoleEnum` like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum RoleEnum
{
    Administrator,
    Moderator,
    User,
    Guest,
}
```

Let's say that you then have a function that needs to check whether the user is has one of a number of roles.  It may look something like this:

```
public bool IsInAnyRole(RoleEnum userRoles)
{
    bool ok = false;
    if (userRoles.HasFlag(RoleEnum.Administrator))
    {
       ok |= IsInRole("Administrator");
    }
    if (userRoles.HasFlag(RoleEnum.Moderator))
    {
       ok |= IsInRole("Moderator");
    }
    if (userRoles.HasFlag(RoleEnum.User))
    {
       ok |= IsInRole("User");
    }
    if (userRoles.HasFlag(RoleEnum.Guest))
    {
       ok |= IsInRole("Guest");
    }
    return ok;
}
```

*(changing `|=` to `&=` would change the function into `IsInAllRoles`)*

Which would then be callable as

```
bool inRole = IsInAnyRole(RoleEnum.Administrator | RoleEnum.Moderator);
```